# Visual studio project.json does not have a runtime section

Tags: json, visual-studio-2017

I ran into a error in visual studio 2017, I'm searching over the net but I don't find anything usefull, so my question is, how can I solve this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Your project.json doesn't have a runtimes section. You should add '"runtimes": { "win": { } }' to your project.json and then re-run NuGet restore.

I was seaching for file where is located in my project but with no succsess.

Thanks

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: yes, I've deleted the whole project and cloned it from git

Answer (score 42):

I got rid of this problem by manually deleting Visual Studio `obj` folder of the project that it's complaining about (the 'Clean Solution' command wasn't getting rid of it).
I found the answer through [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30414/after-march-14th-update-porjects-without-projectjs.html) and [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4163) threads.

Comment: Great! You save me a lot of time! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, removing obj/projects.assets.json was enough in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after trying to migrate all my projects to the new .csproj format manually. I had an issue with one projet in the new format, so I reverted from git, and this message started to show up.

What I did:

- Closed VS
- Removed the `.vs` folder
- Removed the `packages` folder
- Restarted VS
- Tried to build
- Had issues with namespaces not found, as if packages were not installed
- Opened NuGet package manager console
- Ran `Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName <project>`

Problem gone!

Hope it helps someone with the same issue :)

Comment: I had the same issue with migrating and restoring the csproj format manually, too. And I've tried your procedure but nothing helped.

Comment: I need to do both: delete `obj` and `Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName <project>` in the NuGet console. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded a NuGet Package.

Then I undid some changes for the project, but the NuGet Packege had created a json file called project inside the project folder.

Inside this file, I could find runtimes.

But I just deleted this json file and built again.